# Is there an abstract slicing object that can be used to return empty data in a pandas Series or DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I want to have a function that returns an indexing object that can be used for filtering elements in a pandas Series or DataFrame. Aside from a matrix of `False` values, is there a way to return something that can be used for slicing and will always return an empty data set?

I want to use this as `mydata[runtime_filter(mydata)]` where `runtime_filter` is something determined at runtime, so I'm looking for a way to select no values, but as a slice object, rather than a boolean indexing object, which may be large. (In cases where `runtime_filter` needs to select some values but not others, I can't avoid a boolean indexing object.)

For example, this works to select all data:

```
def find_all(some_series):
    return slice(None)
```

so that `mydata[find_all(mydata)]` is essentially equivalent to `mydata[:]`.

Is there a way to return something simple that will return an empty set?

```
def find_none(some_series):
    return ?????
```

---

(In cases where I actually care about the data, then I need to return a boolean indexing object; for example, this will return an indexing object that is True for values greater than 7, otherwise False:

```
def find_greater_than_7(some_series):
    return some_series > 7
```

and I can use `mydata[find_greater_than_7(mydata)]` to extract a subset of the data.)

Comment: What about `some_series != some_series`?

Comment: @BrenBarn Won't work when series has `NaN`

Comment: Also that's a simple implementation, but it returns a huge object if the series itself is huge, and I was hoping to apply something simple.

Comment: Use `return pd.Series(False, index=some_series.index)` perhaps?

Comment: @JasonS: Your `some_series > 7` already returns an object of the same size as the original series.

Comment: Or `return slice(0)]`?

Comment: @JasonS if you mean an empty object with the same structure then `object[:0]`.

Comment: @BrenBarn but there's no choice for predicates that return a mix of `True` and `False` values.

Comment: Gotta love those downvoters. If I knew ahead of time exactly what question I wanted to ask, with exactly correct terminology, and could state it in a perfectly clear way, then I could probably get the answer by myself and wouldn't need to post a question. There should be wiggle room for people asking questions to work their way towards a clear question before people throw -1s at it.

Answer (score 2):

You could try a slice whose end is before its start, like `slice(2, 1)`.

Comment: I'd say this is the same concept as @Zero's `slice(0)`

Comment: yeah, that's the only thing that seems to work, although it seems somewhat wrong, and not sure it will work if the index is not numeric.

Comment: @JasonS: I tested it with a non-numeric index, it seems to work.

Comment: @JasonS `pd.DataFrame(np.ones((4, 4)), list('abcd'), list('wxyz'))[slice(0)]` slices the index.

Comment: `slice(0)` is cleaner, but yeah, this works. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Returning an empty list would suffice if you use `df.loc` instead of `df[...]`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def find_none(some_series):
    return []

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,4)))
print(df.loc[find_none('foo')])
```

prints

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [0, 1, 2, 3]
Index: []
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't seem to work on DataFrames.

Comment: Oh -- yeah, you got the same result I did; what I'm looking for is to produce an empty *index*, not empty columns.

Comment: Is `loc` better to use than plain indexing?

Comment: @JasonS: I like to use `df.loc` instead of `df` for boolean masking. Not only is it a little bit faster, it also helps me know that whenever I read `df[...]` it is selecting columns, never rows.

Comment: interesting... "little bit faster" -- is that documented somewhere?

Comment: @JasonS: That has just been my personal experience. The Pandas code needs to do tests to determine if the indexing object in `df[...]` should be used to return columns or rows. It then dispatches to `df.loc`. By using `df.loc`, you save Pandas that step, and your code is a little more explicit.

Comment: @unutbu -- I think OP asked for series, so, yours should work as is, without needing `loc`. And, I like this.

Comment: @Zero: I think the OP wants a DataFrame with an empty index. `df[[]].index.empty` is False, but `df.loc[[]].index.empty` is True.

Answer (score 0):

based on @BrenBarn and @Zero's answers, I'm using this:

```
class Everything(object):
    def __call__(self, data):
        return slice(None)
    def __invert__(self):
        return Nothing()
    def __and__(self, other):
        return other
    def __or__(self, other):
        return self

class Nothing(object):
    def __call__(self, data):
        return slice(0)
    def __invert__(self):
        return Everything()
    def __and__(self, other):
        return self
    def __or__(self, other):
        return other
```

and then I can also use operations like

```
mydata[filter1 & ~filter2]
```

which are compatible with `Everything()` and `Nothing()` as one of the filters.